# Number of online users

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 35 users. The probability that one specific user is online is $\frac{1}{10}$. What is the probability that 11 or more users are simultanious online?

I thought that $P(n=\text{number of users online simultaniously})=\frac{1}{10}^n \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{35-n} = \frac{1}{9}^n \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{35}$.

So $P(\ge \text{11 users are online simultaniously})=P(n=11)+P(n=12)+...+P(n=35)=\frac{9}{10}^35 \cdot \frac{9}{8} \cdot ((\frac{1}{9})^{11}-(\frac{1}{9})^{36})$. But, according to the book, it should be 0.0004 which is clearly not what I have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This assumes that two different users being online are independent events. In reality, their online periods probably clump in the same hours of the day, so they are not likely to be independent.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot your binomial coefficients, that's all. This accounts for the number of different ways you can select $n$ online users from the 35 in total.

So in fact:

$P(n) = {35 \choose n} \cdot \frac{1}{10}^n \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{35-n} = {35 \choose n} \cdot \frac{1}{9}^n \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{35}$

Comment: As a side note this is precisely a modeling problem with the Binomial distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @Bunder: Indeed. I sort of assumed he's studied this a little at least and this will ring bells for him. :)